# cannot create topic in kafka

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to create a topic in Kafka `2.12.2.2` at ubuntu but I keep getting an issue with zookeeper

zookeeper and Kafka are running and I tried to run the following command in Kafka directory:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testing
```

the error that I keep gettings:

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:242)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:238)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:96)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1825)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:262)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:53)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Comment: check your firewall settings.

Comment: Check the bootstrap port you are connecting to.

Comment: Is itt a docker image you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Have you checked if the zookeeper is running?

Comment: Run $telnet localhost 2181  first of all to see if zookeper is running there and if you don't have connectivity issues.

Comment: it seems that the issue is the zookeeper when I run zookeeper its look like it is stuck .. the last log I see it : [2019-09-03 09:18:07,749] INFO Creating new log file: log.50 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog)  what could cause this issue?